# What is the best way to render a screen change?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am making an app that changes screen layout on an event detection, i.e. When the mobile detects a BLE signal, it should load the interface according to the id received. What should be the best way to do it? (setState for a variable)

```
DeviceEventEmitter.addListener(someevent, () => {
    this.setState({some variable})
});
.....
render() {

    if (this.state.some variable) {
        return();
    }else {
        return (
            regular interface
        );
    }
}
```

this is how I do it currently, I cannot navigate to different page, as this page contains listeners for two events, exit and entry. Also if i use react native router flux with API calls and loading huge data, would it affect speed?

Comment: please, be careful of indentation when you are asking a question

Comment: This is just a sample code to show what functionality I am using, will take care next time